# How do you disable hands-free mode on airpods on mac?

Tags: macos, airpods

I got airpods recently, but whenever I join calls using the airpods as an input and output device, the earphones go into hands-free mode, and the audio quality dies. I know this is a problem for all bluetooth devices, but I did some researching and I found its possible to turn this off in windows, but theres nothing I could find about disabling HFM on MacOS, which I use. I found this old [article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7495115)  which has a terminal command for OSX El Capitan, which I tried but doesn't do anything. Is it possible on Mac natively, or with third party software etc?

Comment: What are you using as a microphone?

Comment: The airpods microphone

Comment: Then you are stuck with low quality - they only way would possible to use another microphone.